# how to get every inputs signature from a raw hex bitcoin transaction using python?

Tags: raw-transaction, python, python-bitcoinlib

I have this raw transaction :
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

It has 5 inputs, and I would like to get the signatures of all of them.
I can use bitcoinlib to get the info about this transaction, but the info doesnt give me the signatures.

I used 'transaction_deserialize()' from the transaction module to get the info.

I already have, server=1 and txindex=1, into the bitcoin.conf file

How can I decript any raw transaction to get the signature of all the inputs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/93711/how-do-i-to-get-the-r-s-and-z-values-from-a-raw-transaction-version-2

Comment: it seems to be great indeed, but I dont know how to use this with python, do i have to install bitcoin-cli?

Comment: Yes you'd need to install Bitcoin Core which includes bitcoin-cli. If you want to use Python specifically can you make that clear in the question please? I'll look over some Python libraries and get back to you.

Comment: ok, I will make the change to my question, it was not clear that i wanted to use python. Thank you for your help bro

Comment: There's this too https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/78452/does-exist-some-library-for-decode-encode-raw-transaction. I haven't used this library though so can't comment if it works, is sufficiently maintained etc https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools

Comment: thanks for your help man, I will try this out to see how it is working, It seems to be what i was looking for, I will come back here if this worked well. Thx.

Comment: I tried two different packages, the one that you suggested and https://github.com/primal100/pybitcointools
I think that the one that you suggested is easier to use and the information I need are extracted in a better fashion.
Thank you for your help, have a great day.

Comment: No problem. Marking this is a duplicate as the above answered your question.